# Is there a word for people who are oblivious of the atmosphere around them?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, synonyms

For example, is there a word to describe a little girl who just sits on the sofa watching tv happily while her parents are fighting — as though she were in her own "happy place" and behaving normally?

This is for an art assignment. I have to draw a picture illustrating a word. I want to draw a scene similar to the one I described, but I don't know any words that would fit.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/oblivious

Comment: How about *unfazed*?

Comment: I suggest there is not, because mot obviously, no one term could really encompass blind, deaf, selfish or insensitive people, among others.

If "Draw a picture illustrating a word" is the only instruction you've been given, why not choose a word you're comfortable with?

If that's not the only instruction, what was left out?

Comment: And I would note that "living in a vacuum" literally fits the criterion of the title.

Answer (score 1):

*engrossed*

adjective
having all one's attention or interest absorbed by someone or something.
"they seemed to be engrossed in conversation"

from Oxford

Answer (score 0):

**Unconcerned** seems to fit the attitude you mentioned.

from [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconcerned)

- unconcerned (adj) - not involved : not having any part or interest,  suggests a lack of sensitivity or regard for others' needs or troubles.
- **unconcernedness** (noun)
- unconcernedly (adverb)

Answer (score -1):

How about **zoned out**? From M-W:

> [**zone out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zone%20out): to become oblivious to one's surroundings especially in order to relax